# How to find minimum moves to set all elements in array to 0?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, permutation

I encountered a problem of counting minimum moves to set all elements in array to 0. An array consist of integer values from 0 to 6 (including 6) and the conditions are:

1. It is possible to change one or more subsequent values in one step (move) by the same value e.g. change values from index 5 to 8 (so indexes 5, 6, 7, 8) by adding 2 but it is forbidden to change indexes 5, 6, 8 (without 7, so they are not subsequent) by adding 2 in one step (I would have to change 5, 6 firstly and then in next step 8 to do it correctly).
2. Array consist of values from 0 to 6 e.g. when value is 5 and you add 3, it will be set on 1 because 6 is maximum and with value higher than 6 it ,,goes from start (0)" or if value is 1 and you substract 2, finally it will be set on 6 because 0 is minimum and with value lower than 0 it ,,goes from end (6)". In other words -1 will be equal to 6, -2 equal to 5, 8 equal to 1.

I have to write algorithm, which solves described problem and have no idea how should I start.

I tried to count occurrences of every number and then in first step set values to 0 in array from first occurrence to last but using this approach in some cases answer is wrong. For example array with values {1,3,2,2,2}. Step 1 - set 2 to 0 {1,3,0,0,0} and then in two separated moves set 1 and 3 to 0 what finally gives 3 moves. Valid answer is 2 moves because in first step values from 3 to last 2 should be decreased by 2 - {1,1,0,0,0} and then in next move decrease first two values by 1 - so 2 moves.

Comment: For your information, what you describe in 2. is called a modulo operation (here modulo 7). For you problem, write your approach and the example where it fails.